# Identificar CSS não carregado em com Firebug?

Tags: css, firebug, firewall

Tenho um Site hospedado na LocaWeb, e possuo um **firewall** na empresa **PFSense** que por algum motivo está impedindo o carregamento do CSS nas maquinas da minha rede. Quero saber como faço para identificar o que não está carregando na página, pra que possa fazer alguma regra afim de resolver este problema. vi que é possível fazer com o **firebug**. Mas ainda não sei como. Caso alguém possa me ajudar serei grato

Answer (score 1):

Não chega a ser necessário utilizar o Firebug, pode monitorar a rede pelo próprio navegador:

- Pressione <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>;
- Acesse a aba "Rede" e recarregue a página que gostaria de monitorar.

O resultado será semelhante a este *(que executei na página dessa pergunta)*:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Grato pela resposta, no meu caso está o seguinte: Tenho alguns css que não carregam quando estou pelo firewall. Na coluna **"TRANSFERIDO"** fica apenas com aquele risco que também apareceu no seu exemplo o que isso significa ?